# 1N4001 diode in series with battery

Tags: batteries, diodes

I have a door bell that uses 2 AA batteries.

I want to use a 18650 — would it work in such an application?

It was recommended to use a 18650 in series with a Si diode, such as a 1N4001? The 0.6V drop should reduce the voltage sufficient to be considered safe.

How would I hook that up? A diagram if possible would help.

Comment: Don't forget that a fully charged lithium cell can be up to 4.35V, depending on the chemistry.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use a pair of rechargeable AAs?

Comment: @anrieff Rechargeable AAs don't have the capacity that 18650's do.

Comment: If capacity is important, then you'll probably be better off with a micropower step-down converter to drop the varying voltage of the Li-Ion to 3V. That would give you even longer running time. What's current being drawn from the doorbell?

Comment: I do not what current is being drawn. Can I test with a multimeter?

Comment: Would a 3V 1A 1000mA AC Adapter to DC Power Supply Charger work?           https://www.ebay.com/itm/3V-1A-1000mA-AC-Adapter-to-DC-Power-Supply-Charger-Cord-5-5-2-1mm-Plug-RS/113395755704?hash=item1a66e9eab8:g:dCAAAOSwhcdak2op:rk:23:pf:0#rwid

Comment: 1) Yes, you can test it, in current measurement mode. I think almost all multimeters have it. 2) Yes, this adapter would work, actually 1A is an overkill as the doorbell probably requires a tiny current, at least a few orders of magnitude smaller, but that would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the diode there is on two sides a wire. If you look at the diode itself there is a stripe on one side of the diode (close to one wire). If you connect the OTHER wire to the + of the battery, and the wire with the stripe to the + of your door bell. and of course the - of the battery to the - of your door bell.

Comment: Generally component "wires" are referred to as "leads." You may also want to include an image and/or mention cathode/anode as labels for the terminals of a diode.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the doorbell.

A pair of AA batteries in series will supply a voltage from 3V down to 1.8V, depending on their state of charge.  A LiIon battery will work from 4.2V (or 4.35V if you're sporting when you charge it) down to about 3.2V.

But the doorbell may be OK with the higher voltage -- or not.  **Two** diodes in series may do.

The big problem with your scheme, however, is that LiIon cells are permanently damaged when you let their voltage drop below 3.2V per cell (or so -- it depends on the way the cell is manufactured, and on how long you want it to last).  A device like your doorbell that's designed to just suck a pair of AA cells dry will use up the LiIon cell past the point where it can be safely recharged unless you use some sort of a protection circuit, and that's way more complicated than a couple of diodes.

Comment: I will check voltage so it never drops below 3 volts. I can also put more batteries in series and increase it's run time.

Comment: Actually it's pretty easy to buy a 18650 with internal protection circuit. It's fairly common use for e.g. flashlights.

Comment: @anrieff I had not realized that.  Too deep in product development, I guess.